# run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)': The data has been changed

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I am running into a pop-up message that reads "run-time error '-2147352567 (80020009)': The data has been changed". I am trying to simply convert the typed in value to all uppercase. The code looks like below:

```
If IsNumeric(Me.Results) = False Then

'Capatilizing the results field
Me.Results = UCase(Me.Results)

End If
```

Once I hit debug, I am able to run the Private Sub Results_AfterUpdate() and it works just fine. How can I avoid this message?

"Me.Results = UCase(Me.Results)" is highlighted when I debug.

Thank you, Adam

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26912290/How-to-solve-runtime-error-'2147352567-80020009-'.html

Comment: This situation is a bit different than mine. I am trying to make the non-numerical value all uppercase, not replace the value with a different one. Any ideas?